# Get custom WCF object with Json

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, json, wcf

**[SOLVED]**

I have made a little test project to lean how to work with WCF objects and Json. If you have any good resources/tutorials on doing so, please let me know.

I am trying to get a custom object `User` by it's `id` with some jQuery script, when doing so my service fails with no message. Returning "known" objects like `int` or `string` works alright so I think my `web.config` should be fine

**IService**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{   
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    User GetUser(int id);       
}

[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

**Service.svc.cs**

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode
= AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 : IService
{  
    public User GetUser(int id)
    {
        return new User() { id=1, name="foo" };
    }
}
```

**Json**

```
var Type;
var Url;
var Data;
var ContentType;
var DataType;
var ProcessData;    

$(document).ready(
        function() {
            $("#log").append("<p>Document ready</p>");
            GetUser();
        }
    );  

function GetUser() {
        $("#log").append("<p>Called GetUser</p>");
        var userid = "1";
        Type = "POST";
        Url = "http://localhost:4270/Service.svc/GetUser";
        Data = '{"Id": "' + userid + '"}';
        ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        DataType = "json"; 
        varProcessData = true; 
        CallService();
    }

function CallService() {
        $("#log").append("<p>Called CallService</p>");
        $.ajax({
            type: Type,
            url: Url,
            data: Data,
            contentType: ContentType,
            dataType: DataType,
            processdata: ProcessData,
            success: function(msg) {
                ServiceSucceeded(msg);
            },
            error: ServiceFailed
        });
    }

function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
        $("#log").append("<p>ServiceSucceeded</p>");
        if (DataType == "json") {
            user = result.GetUserResult;
            $("#result").append("<p> user = " +user+ "</p>");
            $("#result").append("<p> id = " +user.id+ "</p>");
            $("#result").append("<p> name = " +user.name+ "</p>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it clear? you invoke the *GetUser* recursively without any stopping contition. `return GetUser(Convert.ToInt32(id));`

Comment: Yes.. after proof reading I saw it immediately..
I had another error and will edit my question.

Comment: I've noticed another problem regarding your jQuery. You arent passing the ajax values to CallService so your ajax call wont work. TYPE, URL, DATA, CONTENTTYPE etc are all undefined variables in the scope of that function. you need to pass these over from your getUser() method

Comment: @heymega These are defined as global variables. I will edit my post

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the case of your post data?

so this:

```
Data = '{"Id": "' + userid + '"}';
```

Should be this:

```
Data = '{"id": "' + userid + '"}';
```